# store boolean value in sqlite android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to save the state of checkbox and set to true in case of checked or vice versa. I am setting a method in sqlite but still unable to store the boolean value. I am aware that it is stored in form of 1 or 0 but still could not do so. When I store an int, it is giving an error

```
private static final int STATUS = 0;
private static final String CHECKBOX_POS = "checkbox_pos";

 @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String create_table = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "( "
                + "ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ,"
                +  STATUS + " INTEGER NOT NULL, "
                +  CHECKBOX_POS + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                )";
        db.execSQL(create_table);

    }
 @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
       
        if (oldVersion < 2) {
            db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ADD COLUMN " + STATUS +
                    " INTEGER ");
        }

 public boolean insertPos(String position,
                                        int checkbox_status){
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(CHECKBOX_POS,position);
        contentValues.put(STATUS,checkbox_status);

        long result = database.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);

        if (result == -1){
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }


    }
```

This is giving errors `<column definition name> or <table constraint> expected, got '0'` in `onCreate` and `<column definition name> expected, got '0'` at line
`db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ADD COLUMN " + STATUS + " INTEGER ");`

I need to use this in the following way

```
if (isChecked){
boolean success = db.insertPos(
                            String.valueOf(checkbox_pos),
                            // the boolean value to be inserted);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have defined:

```
private static final int STATUS = 0;
```

So, `STATUS` is an integer variable but you are using it as the name of a column here:

```
String create_table = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "( "
                + "ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ,"
                +  STATUS + " INTEGER NOT NULL, "
                +  CHECKBOX_POS + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                )";
```

here:

```
db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ADD COLUMN " + STATUS +                   " INTEGER ");
```

and here:

```
contentValues.put(STATUS,checkbox_status);
```

Change the definition of `STATUS` so that it is a string that can be used as a column's name:

```
private static final String STATUS = "status";
```

Comment: but how would I use that string value "status" for boolean status in  `boolean success = db.insertPos(
                            String.valueOf(checkbox_pos),
                            // the boolean value to be inserted);` I need to set it to true as it is under `ifChecked()`.

Comment: @user16566034 The string value "status" is the name of the column where you will store 0 or 1, just like "checkbox_pos" is the name of the other column.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that point but now I need to set the boolean value in the `boolean success = db.insertPos(String.valueOf(checkbox_pos), // the boolean value to be inserted);` . If its 1 or 0 how would it convert to true or false?

Comment: @user16566034 For SQLite TRUE is 1 and FALSE is 0. There is no need to convert anything.